# Out of universe, why was Seven-of-Nine introduced?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Seven of Nine, along with *Voyager's* encounter with the Borg, to me anyway, seems to quite suddenly appear.  **Out-of-universe, what was the reason to introduce the new character of Seven-of-Nine midway through the series *Voyager*?**

Comment: Did you not see her? http://trekcore.com/gallery/albums/sevenofnine/7of9_s4a.jpg

Comment: Semi dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79102/what-was-the-reason-behind-kes-being-removed-from-star-trek-voyager

Comment: Falling ratings, so introduce eye candy. They were originally going to kill off Kim but Garrett Wong placed on some "sexiest people on TV" list so Kes got the chop.

Comment: @Richard evidently the producers hadn't seen her earlier, otherwise they'd have included her way earlier!

Comment: Apparently they 'had' to get rid of someone (the idea of Kim, then Kes) because they wanted a main cast of nine people. God knows why they couldn't just add Seven of Nine and keep Kes - apparently no one in the cast was happy that Jennifer Lien was fired.

Comment: @ThruGog Seven wouldn't have been Seven **of nine** if there had been ten crew in the case ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an interview with [Stephen Poe](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stephen_Edward_Poe), this very issue was raised:

> Q: Why was Seven (Jeri Ryan) a Borg picked as the new character? Was
>   is sex appeal or something else? Pat
>
> SP: Good question. Seven functions on two levels. First, **she provides
>   the perfect foil for Janeway- something Voyager did not have
>   previously. Kirk had Spock, Picard had Data, but Janeway's foil was
>   missing.** The result is, Janeway's character has been strengthened
>   significantly. This is very apparent throughout this current season.
>   Second, **Seven is a perfect example of something Star Trek has always
>   done superbly well: force each of us as viewers to look in the mirror
>   again and realize this too is part of what it's like to be human. In
>   this case, it forces us to confront old ideas, stereotypical images,
>   pre-conceived notions.** At first look, Seven appears to be blatant T&A
>   aimed squarely at the male demographic. But if we can get past that
>   "image" what do we see? A character who, because she was raised by the
>   Borg, has not got a clue as to what effect her appearance might have
>   on a male crewmember. In that sense she is sexless. What we then
>   discover is here is a FEMALE character (do I have to shout Hooray!?)
>   who is strong-willed, independent, tough, takes no crap from the
>   Captain, calls everyone on their hypocrisies and silliness ---whoa!
>   That's one heck of a role model for women everywhere. Jeri Ryan told
>   me one day when we were discussing this point that she gets a lot of
>   mail from women and the letters generally all start out the same way:
>   "I really, really, really did not want to like your character - but I
>   do. "

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20011007000955/http://www.startrek.com/news/transcripts/poe_040298.html)

However, I suspect aiming to improve ratings was probably also one of the angles.  Considering that Seven essentially replaced Kes, if things had been working well, there probably wouldn't be a need to change the format.  As explained in [this article](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/02/07/tv/signoff-intergalactic-generation-gap.html) from the time, the ratings of *Voyager* were increased by *60 percent* following Seven's introduction.

Comment: I seem to recall she was placed onto a restrictive diet for the duration of filming due to the tightness of her suit. Yay strong female role model!

Comment: @Richard apparently she blacked out a couple of times her suit was so tight so they had to change it - a bit more dramatic than the Picard Manoeuvre (the shirt-tug that is)

Comment: So... it was T&A yadda yadda yadda excuses excuses T&A after all? :P