# Besides those who did, did any other Star Trek cast members come close to leaving?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actors

Of course we have:

- [Tasha Yar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104804/whats-the-story-behind-the-departure-of-tasha-yar-denise-crosby) (Denise Crosby)
- [Dr. Crusher](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22969/why-was-crusher-replaced-with-pulaski-who-was-replaced-by-crusher) (Gates McFadden) who left for a season
- [Jadzia Dax](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33913/why-was-jadzia-dax-written-out-of-star-trek-deep-space-nine-so-late) (Terry Farrell)
- [Kes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79102/what-was-the-reason-behind-kes-being-removed-from-star-trek-voyager) (Jennifer Lien)

(Links are to related questions)

## Were there any other main cast members who came close to leaving?

Comment: Strangely, all female.

Comment: You've forgotten [Geneviève Bujold](http://www.blastr.com/2013-1-18/why-voyagers-1st-capt-thought-she-was-good-fit-wasnt)

Comment: You also forgot Dr. Polaski (Diana Muldaur).  She was technically part of the main cast for that one season when Crusher was gone, and then never heard from again (as far as I know).  She certainly has a more legit claim than Bujold's, given that she was there for a whole season and even had several whole episodes where she was the main character.

Comment: This question does not currently, but might want to distinguish between cast members who left, and cast members who ... were removed. Looking at the question as it stands, as far as I remember, Gates McFadden and Jennifer Lien were rather written out of the respective shows against their will (?)

Comment: Muldaur was a "special guest appearance" in those episodes she appeared in. She was never in the main cast.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: The OP will have to decide whether or not to consider that a technicality. From the PoV of the audience, for all intents and purposes, she *was* a cast member - she appeared on the [season 2 cast photo](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/1/1a/TNGCrewSeason2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20060920144135&path-prefix=en), she held a permanent, important position among the crew, and she appeared in (nearly?) all episodes of the season. Most viewers probably couldn't care less when the actress is credited, or how her name is labeled on screen.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman, the question is about cast members who didn't leave,  so it really doesn't matter whether we count Muldaur or not because she did in fact leave.

Comment: Re: Muldaur's credit - it was also never in the main opening

Answer (score 44):

**Uhura**

Nichelle Nichols came very close to leaving but was convinced by Martin Luther King Jr to stay, being one of the few recurring black actresses of the time in a positive role.

Her wiki article goes over it, and her autobiography is worth a read.

> Nichols' Star Trek character, one of the first African American female
>   characters on American television not portrayed as a servant, was
>   groundbreaking in U.S. society at the time. Civil rights leader Martin
>   Luther King, Jr. personally praised her work on the show and asked her
>   to remain when she considered leaving the series.

[Nichelle Nichols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichelle_Nichols)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this story was also discussed in her interview with Neil DeGrasse Tyson on Startalk ([Link](http://www.startalkradio.net/show/a-conversation-with-nichelle-nichols/))

Answer (score 36):

### Worf

According to [this article](http://www.trektoday.com/news/230106_03.shtml) in TrekToday, **Michael Dorn** (Lt. Worf) nearly left the show after the second season, stating that his makeup was causing damage to his skin:

> Dorn said that he was very happy when his makeup time was reduced from
>   two and a half hours to a little over and *(sic)* hour, confessing that he
>   nearly left the show after the second season because of all the damage
>   to his skin. At one time he did a convention nearly every weekend, but
>   now he does 3–4 a year, "the really cool places" like Italy and
>   Germany. For fun he flies ex-military jets.

### Sulu

This [Comic-con interview report](http://www.trekcon.de/fedcon-2012.html) states that **George Takei** (Sulu) nearly left the original series after he was made to share a dressing room with Walter Koenig (Chekov):

> When Takei returned, the two had to share a dressing room and a single
>   episode script. This reportedly angered Takei to the point where he
>   nearly left the show. But the two actors have since become good
>   friends, and the image of their two characters manning the helm of the
>   Enterprise became iconic.

### Spock

According to [Star Trek: These Are the Voyages TOS Season 2: Season Two](http://www.amazon.ca/Star-Trek-These-Voyages-Season/dp/0989238148), Leonard Nimoy almost didn't return for season two of TOS due to contractual issues. There are additional details on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/TOS_Season_2):

> Nimoy's agent had asked for Nimoy's salary to be increased from
>   US$1,250 per episode during the first season to US$9,000 for the
>   second season. Eventually a compromise figure of US$2,500 per episode
>   was reached and Nimoy signed on for the second season.

### Janeway

According to an [interview with Starlog](https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-268/268_djvu.txt), Kate Mulgrew said that she considered refusing to sign for a seventh season, citing her impatience at being made to wait around all day for pick-up shots in episodes focusing on other members of the cast. Ultimately, the show's producers were able to work things out with her:

> ...she would be sitting at home for hours, unable to go anywhere or do
>   anything, waiting for production to call her in. And she didn't want
>   too many more instances in which she shot only a single, non-essential
>   scene.
>
> Berman and company heard Mulgrew out, and ultimately they came to an
>   agreement that satisfied everyone. Janeway wouldn't be pulling a
>   vanishing act this year or next. Just how  close, though, did we come
>   to losing Mulgrew? "If they had  said to me, 'We really don't care,'
>   I may have considered leaving," she responds. "I was under contract
>   already for the sixth year and I intended to honor that contract.
>   I'm only talking about conversations and negotiations for the
>   seventh season. It really involved my happiness quotient. In
>   many ways, I set the tone on the set. My mood and my approach are
>   very important, and I think there's nothing worse than a professional
>   actress who is unhappy because she misses her husband and
>   children. But [Berman and  Braga] realized that. And if I may say so,
>   they were not only gentlemen about it, but very gracious. I am much,
>   much happier now."

Comment: I believe Nimoy only signed on for Wrath of Kahn on the proviso that he would be killed off and had no intention of returning. Obviously changed his mind

Comment: @CarlSixsmith - It's astounding how much people's minds change when you offer them huge piles of cash.

Comment: also when three men and a little lady isn't as successful as its predecessor

Comment: Funny - just can't imagine Takei being angry!

Comment: Great research = a very informative read!

Answer (score 3):

#### Benjamin Sisko

On the DVD interviews for DS9, Avery Brooks (Commander/Captain Benjamin Sisko) said that he wanted to quit, but at the time had just explained to his son the importance of sticking to your commitments, so he remained.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which DVD interviews and what were his exact words?