# Was there a plan for development for Worf and Tasha Yar?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, character-development, worf, tasha-yar

In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, there were two slightly similar "warrior" characters - Tasha Yar and Worf. Eventually, Worf moved into be the head of security and took on the kind of "tough guy" role, which seems like a natural progression from how he was established in series 1.

However this was only possible because Denise left / Tasha died. Have the writers/creators spoken about how both characters might have progressed had she stayed for the long haul? Although Tasha's role as the fighter was rarely demonstrated, it's clear that this was what was intended for her, and it's unusual for an ensemble TV show such as this to have two characters so similar without one of them ending up a little redundant.

(I know we got a taste of Tasha's maturing in *Yesterday's Enterprise* but this time it was without Worf, so the question remains)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the story behind the departure of Tasha Yar (Denise Crosby)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104804/whats-the-story-behind-the-departure-of-tasha-yar-denise-crosby)

Comment: You only have this impression because of where Worf evolved to after Yar died.   At the time, he was just generic junior lieutenant bridge officer.   Worf didn't have to become Fighter Dude.

Comment: Interestingly, I recently watched "Skin of Evil", the episode wherein Tasha dies, and there did seem to be a "moment" between them at the start of the episode. Can't really read much into that since presumaby they knew she would die while writing that scene...

Answer (score 8):

Denise Crosby:

> I wanted to leave as I was struggling with not being able to do much with the character.

[from startrek.com (archive link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080505043153/http://www.startrek.com/startrek/view/community/chat/archive/transcript/1120.html)

It seems unlikely that there was a plan for the character if the actor had a problem with not being able to do anything with the character.